# ¿Cómo ordenar n pares de coordenadas x, y en base a x?

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Hola a todos tengo que ordenar n pares de coordenadas x,y en base a x sin utilizar matrices solo arreglos, lo intente hacer con el método de la burbuja, y funciona pero cuando son demasiadas coordenadas se vuelve demasiado lento, alguna sugerencia de como lo podría hacer?

Este es mi código

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,temp1=0,temp2=0;
    printf("Ingresa el numero de coordenadas: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int cordenadax[n],cordenaday[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Coordenada %d\n",i+1);

        printf("Ingresa x: ");
        scanf("%d",&cordenadax[i]);
        printf("Ingresa y: ");
        scanf("%d",&cordenaday[i]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++){
            if(cordenadax[j]>cordenadax[j+1]){
                temp1 = cordenadax[j];
                temp2 = cordenaday[j];

                cordenadax[j] = cordenadax[j+1];
                cordenaday[j] = cordenaday[j+1];

                cordenadax[j+1] = temp1;
                cordenaday[j+1] = temp2;
             }
        }
    }
    printf("\nCoordenadas ordenadas en base a x\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("X:%d Y:%d\n",cordenadax[i],cordenaday[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo de entrada y salida
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece interesante, pero me cuesta un poquito de trabajo seguir todo tu código. ¿Podrías poner al final de tu post, un ejemplo de entrada de datos y un ejemplo de salida?

Comment: listo ya lo edite

Comment: el algoritmo de ordenamiento burbuja es bastante ineficiente, aunque es el mas facil implementar, mientras mas grande y desordenado sea el conjunto mas lento es. Te recomiendo inversigar el ordenamiento por insercion.

Comment: Si hay dos pares con la misma `x`, tomarías en cuenta la `y` también? O simplemente no importa?

Comment: @Mateo no importa que sean iguales

Answer (score 1):

Mi lenguaje C está oxidado, sin embargo, lo que hice fue reescribir el algoritmo quick sort de [este sitio](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/quick-sort), y lo adecué para tu caso.

La única diferencia significativa es que en la función `swap` también realicé la reasignación para las coordenadas de Y.

Además que reescribí el código encapsulándolo para que sea más entendible:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_data(int num_cord, int* coordenadas_x, int* coordenadas_y) {
    for (int i=0; i < num_cord; i++) {
        printf("Tupla %d\n", (i + 1));

        printf("Ingresa X: ");
        scanf("%d", &coordenadas_x[i]);
        
        printf("Ingresa Y: ");
        scanf("%d", &coordenadas_y[i]);
    }
}

void swap(int *primero, int *segundo) {
    int temp = *primero;
    *primero = *segundo;
    *segundo = temp;
}

int partition(int* coordenadas_x, int* coordenadas_y, int low, int high) {
    int pivot = coordenadas_x[high];
    int i = (low - 1);
    
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
        if (coordenadas_x[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(&coordenadas_x[i], &coordenadas_x[j]);
            swap(&coordenadas_y[i], &coordenadas_y[j]);
        }
    }

    swap(&coordenadas_x[i + 1], &coordenadas_x[high]);
    swap(&coordenadas_y[i + 1], &coordenadas_y[high]);
  
    return (i + 1);
}

void sort_coords(int* coordenadas_x, int* coordenadas_y, int low, int high) {
  if (low < high) {
    int pivot = partition(coordenadas_x, coordenadas_y, low, high);
    
    sort_coords(coordenadas_x, coordenadas_y, low, pivot - 1);
    sort_coords(coordenadas_x, coordenadas_y, pivot + 1, high);
  }
}

void print_xy_coords(int* coordenadas_x, int* coordenadas_y, int num_cord) {
    int i=0;
    while (i++ < num_cord)
        printf("%d -> X:%d,Y:%d\n", i, coordenadas_x[i], coordenadas_y[i]);
}

int* initialice_array(int size) {
    return (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
}

int main() {
    int num_cord;

    printf("Ingresa el numero de coordenadas: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_cord);
    
    int* coordenadas_x = initialice_array(num_cord);
    int* coordenadas_y = initialice_array(num_cord);

    get_data(num_cord, coordenadas_x, coordenadas_y);
    sort_coords(coordenadas_x, coordenadas_y, 0, num_cord);

    print_xy_coords(coordenadas_x, coordenadas_y, num_cord);

    free(coordenadas_x);
    free(coordenadas_y);

    return 0;
}
```

Y al ejecutarlo obtienes esto:

```
$ gcc ordenar.c -o ordenar && ./ordenar
Ingresa el numero de coordenadas: 5
Tupla 1
Ingresa X: 5
Ingresa Y: 50
Tupla 2
Ingresa X: 7
Ingresa Y: 70
Tupla 3
Ingresa X: 2
Ingresa Y: 20
Tupla 4
Ingresa X: 8
Ingresa Y: 80
Tupla 5
Ingresa X: 1
Ingresa Y: 10
1 -> X:1,Y:10
2 -> X:2,Y:20
3 -> X:5,Y:50
4 -> X:7,Y:70
5 -> X:8,Y:80
```

Yo utilicé `gcc` en WSL, pero debería ser similar para tu caso.